# footer won't stick in IE compatibility mode (can't find an answer anywhere)

Tags: html, css

Here's the website:

http://www.uiowa.edu/~ucoll/academicmisconduct.shtml

When I go into compatability mode my footer jumps up to the bottom of my header.  I have a wrap with a virtually included header, then a content area, then a virtually included footer (fs-footer).  I'm pretty sure it's something to do with the min-height element.  I've tried a bunch of work arounds and alternatives.  I've also searched googles and forums but haven't found a good answer.  Please help :)

Code:

```
html {
 height: 100%;

}

body {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0 0 0 0;
 font-family: Lucida Grande, Lucida Sans, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 12px;
 background-color:#999;
 background-position:center;
 height: 100%;
}

#wrap {
 width: 1024px;
 height:100%;
 margin: auto;
 padding: 0;
 min-width: 1024px;
 position: relative;
}

#mainContentPage {
 background-image: url(images/backgrounducContent.png);
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 12px;
 width: 1024px;
 margin: 0;
 float: right;
 border-bottom:thick;
 border-bottom-color: #000;
 background-color: #FFF;
 min-height: 100%;
}

.fs-footer {
 clear:both;
 float:left;
 padding-bottom:30px;
 padding-top:0px;
 width:1024px;
 border-top:thick;
 border-top-color:#000;
 border-top-style:groove;
 border-top-width:thick;
 background-color:#FFF;
 background-image:url(images/ucfooter2.png);
 height: auto;

}
```

Comment: Backticks only work for inline code. For multiple lines, indent with four spaces (Ctrl+K).

Comment: new to the site, thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Your markup [does not validate](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.uiowa.edu%2F~ucoll%2Facademicmisconduct.shtml&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0). Could be that there's some unclosed tag somewhere wreaking havoc.

Comment: what version ? ..is this IE8 ?   min-height: 100%; not supported in IE i think

Comment: I'm using IE8, but when I switch to compatibility mode, it messes up my footer.  Compatibility mode views the page as if it were IE7 (I've read, but correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: @hawkeye126: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested in IE8, IE8's Compatibility mode, Firefox:

- From `.fs-footer`, remove `float: left` and add `overflow: auto`.

---

I don't think it's relevant to your problem, but you have code like this:

```
<a href="index.shtml" id="headLink" title="Banner Link">
  <div id="header">
    ...
  </div>
</a>
```

This is not good - you generally should not put block elements (such as `<div>` tags) inside inline elements (such as `<a>` tags).

---

Also, you have:

```
<div id="generalInfoMainContent">

<h1>Classroom Policies - Academic Misconduct</h1>
<p>&nbsp;</p>

<li><a href="academicmisconduct.shtml#fraud">Academic misconduct</a></li>

  <li><a href="academicmisconduct.shtml#consequences">Consequences of Academic misconduct</a></li>
  <li><a href="academicmisconduct.shtml#forgery">Academic Misconduct: Forgery</a></li>
  </ul>
<hr />
```

You appear to be missing an opening `<ul>` tag.

As noted in a comment on your question, you should ensure that your [markup validates](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.uiowa.edu%2F~ucoll%2Facademicmisconduct.shtml&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0).

Answer (score 0):

I always use the following template and it always works fine with all browsers

CSS

```
body, html{
height: 100%;
}

body, p {
margin: 0; padding: 0;
}   

#wrapper {
min-height: 100%;
}

* html #wrapper {
height: 100%;
}



/*HEADER------------------------------------*/
#header {
width: 100%;
background: #666;
}

#header_900 {
width: 960px;
height: 100px;
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
}

/*FOOTER------------------------------------*/
#footer {
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
margin: -100px auto 0 auto; /*THE FIRST no. SHOULD BE EQUAL TO THE FOOTERS HEIGHT*/
position: relative;
background: #666;
}

#footer_900 {
width: 960px;
height: 100px;/*THIS IS THE FOOTERS HEIGHT*/
position: relative;
margin: 0 auto;
}

/*CONTENT------------------------------------*/
#content {
width: 100%;
padding-bottom: 100px; /*THIS SHOULD BE EQUAL TO THE FOOTERS HEIGHT*/
}

#content_900 {
width: 960px;
margin: 0 auto;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

HTML

```
<body>

<div id="wrapper">


    <div id="header">
        <div id="header_900">
            <p>header</p>
        </div><!--header_900-->
    </div><!--header-->


    <div id="content">
        <div id="content_900">
            <p>content</p>
        </div><!--content-->
    </div><!--content-->


</div><!--wrapper-->


<div id="footer">
    <div id="footer_900">
        <p>footer</p>   
    </div><!--footer_900-->
</div><!--footer-->


</body>
```